# Rails HABTM relationship not working with polymorphic relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, polymorphic-associations, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two models: Student and Project.  A student HABTM projects and a Project HABTM students.  Here are the two models:

```
class Student < User
    has_many :relationships, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :employers, through: :relationships
    has_and_belongs_to_many :projects, join_table: :projects_students
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :relationships
    belongs_to :employer
    has_and_belongs_to_many :students, join_table: :projects_students
end
```

As you can see, Student uses polymorphic inheritance from User (The user table has a type column, one of the values is Student).  Here is the controller that creates projects:

```
def create
    @project = current_user.projects.new(project_params)

    respond_to do |format|
        if @project.save
            format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @project }
        else
            format.html { render action: 'new' }
            format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
end

def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:title, :category, :location, :budget,
       :description, :projectdoc)
end
```

Project and Student are connected through the join_table :projects_students:

```
create_table "projects_students", force: true do |t|
  t.integer "student_id"
  t.integer "project_id"
end

add_index "projects_students", ["project_id"], name: "index_projects_students_on_project_id", using: :btree
add_index "projects_students", ["student_id"], name: "index_projects_students_on_student_id", using: :btree
```

The problem is that when a project is created, the student_id is not being passed to the projects_students table.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean to say that Student uses "single table inheritance" rather than "polymorphic inheritance" of which there is no such thing.

That said, since the HABTM association is on users and not students, I'd check in the console to see if this works:

```
Student.first.projects << Project.first
```

Next thing I'd do is to use "build" instead of "new" when instantiating the project:

```
@project = current_user.projects.build project_params
```

I suppose this is only for creating new projects, and that there is a different route for adding students to projects.

Comment: It works in the console.  I tried putting that in the strong parameters, but it doesn't work.  There is no checkbox list - When a student applies to a project, the create method above is envied and I want that student to be the student_id.

Comment: I see. I think you should use "build" instead of "new" when you instantiate the new project.

Comment: Whats the difference?

Comment: Build instantiates the object with the associations set.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're thinking about this wrong.  Generally the `_id` is reserved for foreign keys to a related table.  Since there is no `Student` table, rails may be unable to link the `student_id` in your join table appropriately.

Try changing your join table:

```
create_table "projects_users", force: true do |t|
  t.integer "user_id"
  t.integer "project_id"
end

add_index "projects_users", ["project_id"], name: "index_projects_users_on_project_id", using: :btree
add_index "projects_users", ["user_id"], name: "index_projects_users_on_user_id", using: :btree
```

Your join table shouldn't care about your STI setup.  You can handle that in your models.

So then just cleanup the associations:

```
class Student < User
    has_many :relationships, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :employers, through: :relationships
    has_and_belongs_to_many :projects, join_table: :projects_users, foreign_key: :user_id
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :relationships
    belongs_to :employer
    has_and_belongs_to_many :students, join_table: :projects_users, class_name: 'Student', association_foreign_key: :user_id
end
```